# Outlook VSTO Addin - NormalEmail.dotm not saved

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I'm trying to register a handler for the `WindowSelectionChanged` event. It works, but when quitting Outlook, it will discard any changes to `NormalEmail.dotm` file.

For example, any changes to the *Quick Part Gallery* (Insert->Text->QuickParts) will only be visible during the current session; **closing Outlook and starting it again** will show the previous list of elements, even if they were deleted, or new ones were added).

Deleting the file :

C:\Users[USER]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\ **NormalEmail.dotm**

should prompt Outlook to create a new one, but this won't happen when the Addin is enabled.

This can be reproduced by registering even an empty method to the `WindowSelectionChange` event:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Application.Inspectors.NewInspector += new Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(RegisterChangeHandler);
    }

    void RegisterChangeHandler(Outlook.Inspector inspector)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = Application.ActiveExplorer().ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor?.Application;
-->     app.WindowSelectionChange += WinSelectionChange; <-- this line causes the bug
    }

    private void WinSelectionChange(Selection Sel)
    {
      /* nothing */   
    }
    ...
}
```

This causes no exceptions; the result is the same when putting try/catch blocks in place, or when the callback is unregistered in the `Application.Quit` event.

**Question**: How can Outlook be made to commit the `NormalEmail.dotm` file, while also being able to register a callback for `WindowSelectionChange` event ?

(the project type is "2013 and 2016 VSTO Addin")

Comment: How does your Add-In interact with Word? Can you provide sample code and/or a sequence of steps?

Comment: @Chris In order to reproduce the issue, the code I provided is all you need, really... As you can see, it does not interact with anything at this point. It's just a new project with the callback added to the event.

Comment: What about the NormalEmail.dotm template, and building blocks? The code you posted doesn't do anything at all with that.

Comment: @Chris The code does not interact with building blocks - the user does. It's just that after restarting Outlook all changes are gone!

Comment: Well, I was able to replicate it, but not find a solution. Seems like a bug.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue with Outlook+Word 2013 and Fx 4.0. - Please provide more info about your environment.